# Fulltext Search in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have question on full text search using neo4j. Followed the instruction in the webpage, i enabled the full text search.

[Full Text Search Guide](https://maxdemarzi.com/2016/11/30/enabling-legacy-automatic-full-text-search-on-neo4j-3-x/)

CREATE (p:Place {name:"Chicago"})

```
1) Run the command: START n=node:node_auto_index("name:*C*") RETURN n;
Result: 
+------------------------------+
| n                            |
+------------------------------+
| Node[65263]{name:"Chicago"}  |
+------------------------------+
1 rows

2) Run the command: START n=node:node_auto_index("name:Chicago") RETURN n;
Result:
+---+
| n |
+---+
+---+
0 row

3) START n=node:node_auto_index("name=Chicago") RETURN n;
Result: 
null
```

My question is: How can modify the search (2) START n=node:node_auto_index("name:Chicago") RETURN n; to give the result *Chicago* ?

Also, would we not specify the field name in the command, (i.e. search all fields which contains "Chicago" keyword in all nodes) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use schema indexes for exact matches.

`CREATE INDEX ON :Place(name)`

For more info see
http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/

If you, for some reason, still need to do an exact match try this syntax:

`START n=node:node_auto_index(name="Chicago") RETURN n;`

Comment: Sorry, still can't have the result when run this syntax 
START n=node:node_auto_index(name="Chicago") RETURN n;

Even though if I run this also no result(i.e. search the word which begin with C)
START n=node:node_auto_index("name:C*") RETURN n;

Comment: What is the output of `index --get-config node_auto_index` command (in neo4j-shell)? Did you create the index after you added the data? You may need to reindex the properties e.g. by `MATCH (p:Place) WHERE EXISTS(p.name) SET p.name=p.name`.

Comment: Thanks, it can search exact words after reindex. However, it still not able to search the words start with Ch (ie, START n=node:node_auto_index("name:ch*") RETURN n;). Or i should use "Start with" syntax instead?

Comment: @anthonywong `name:ch*` should work, did you configure the `node_auto_index` as fulltext index? (you can check that using `index --get-config node_auto_index` in neo4j-shell).

Comment: Yes, it is fulltext index now. {    "provider": "lucene",    "type": "fulltext"}.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this ? 
Exact match Chicago -
START n=node:node_auto_index('(name:(Chicago))') RETURN n;

Match all nodes with name property containing Chicago -
START n=node:node_auto_index('(name:(*Chicago*)') RETURN n;